# Regular expression doesn't know where to stop

Tags: php, regex

I have a bunch of documents with tags in it like this (in bold):

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, **\ConsecTeturTitle**. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. \textit{**\QuamLoremTitle**}\specialnote{See {**\EgestasMagnaTitle**}Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.

I'm using this to find them:

```
\\[A-Z].*Title
```

It does good on the first one:

**\ConsecTeturTitle**

But it selects the next two, along with everything in between like this:

**\QuamLoremTitle}\specialnote{See {\EgestasMagnaTitle**

I've been searching to find the answer, but I'm afraid that I don't know enough about RegEx to even know the proper thing to search for.

Basically I need to find every tag that starts with "\" and a capital letter and ends with "Title"; then I need to replace them with "\hl"

I'm planning to do it with PHP like this:

```
preg_replace( '\\[A-Z].*Title', '\hl', $docContents );
```

Any help is MUCH appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That regular expression has a problem: it contains an extra dot. You should use something like this one instead:

```
\\[A-Za-z]+Title
```

The problem with your existing expression is that `.*` matches *any number of characters* and it does so *greedily* (i.e. it never stops as long as it can keep going and still match the `Title` at the end). So what happens is that it starts matching at the "first" match and then continues to gobble up characters until it stops at the "Title" suffix of what should have been the last match.

Comment: Makes sense...
That did it! Thanks a million!